# JQuery Sortable bootstrap table

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

> I'm trying to implement a JQuery sortable bootstrap 3 table. It works
>   fine, but when I drag the row to the position I want it's not actually
>   under the cursor it stays some pixels at the top, which makes it
>   really hard to see what you are dragging.

I'm not sure whether it has to do with my stylesheet or the version of JQuery.

**html**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="sortable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Title
            </th>
            <th>
                Description
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-item-id=3 class="item">
            <td>
                The Voynich Manuscript
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-default pull-right" href="/things/3">show</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-item-id=1 class="item">
            <td>
                A Roman Dodecahedra
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-default pull-right" href="/things/1">show</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-item-id=2 class="item">
            <td>
                A Phaistos Disc
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-default pull-right" href="/things/2">show</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**js**

```
 var cells, desired_width, table_width;
 table_width = $('#sortable').width();
 cells = $('.table').find('tr')[0].cells.length;
 desired_width = table_width / cells + 'px';
 $('.table td').css('width', desired_width);
 $('#sortable').sortable({
     axis: 'y',
     items: '.item',
     cursor: 'move',
     tolerance: 'pointer',
     sort: function(e, ui) {
         return ui.item.addClass('active-item-shadow');
     },
     stop: function(e, ui) {
         ui.item.removeClass('active-item-shadow');
         return ui.item.children('td').effect('highlight', {}, 1000);
     },
     update: function(e, ui) {
         var item_id, position;
         item_id = ui.item.data('item-id');
         console.log(item_id);
         position = ui.item.index();
         console.log(position);
         return $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: '/things/update_row_order',
             dataType: 'json',
             data: {
                 thing: {
                     thing_id: item_id,
                     row_order_position: position
                 }
             }
         });
     }
 });
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Show style sheet also

Comment: Can you please post a picture of what you think. To me it seems ok. If you start to drag it at the bottom of the row, the cursor will stay at the same position, and that is perfectly normal.

Comment: I tested on firefox and IE. I'ts only affecting chrome.